# Linking phones to computer for photos

Tags: windows, android, file-management, networking, file-sharing

I work in an industry where the employees are continually taking photos of vehicles (25+ photos per vehicle) every day.

We currently use a memory card system where we remove the memory card out of the camera and then insert it into the computer manually and then drag and drop each set of photos into a designated folder.

This system has worked well for the last 5+ years, however, as we become increasingly busy, I'm finding the photos are becoming more and more disorganised.

I was thinking of investing in some Android or Apple smart phones that would allow admin to create folders on the computers within the office, that then appear on the smart phone, allowing the employees to select the folder and begin the taking the photos. This would eliminate much of the hassle of having to remove memory cards, organise their photos into specific folders, etc, because they would automatically upload them to the admin's created folders in the office computers.

Could anyone suggest a decent program for this or point me in the right direction of how to get this done?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: In terms of auto upload most android phones allow you to automatically sync your photos to google drive.  The bad news is the users would still have to manually create folders.  You could then copy all the folder from google drive to your system periodically.

Comment: Why remove memory cards? What's wrong with BlueTooth or WiFi? Phones have hose, as do some cameras.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Folders Camera on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.headalsilver.folders_camera&gl=US) and [Camera Folders on App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/folders-camera/id1636474177)

> **About this app**
>
> There are silent camera, normal camera, and video recording modes.
>
> - Photos/videos taken using the app are not saved in the photo box, but in >- the - app's own folder.
> - The app can create and manage folders.
> - Because the created folders are not shown in the list
> - You have to manually enter a name to move to the desired folder.
>   (You can use this to hide your personal folders.)

The last feature looks annoying at first glance, but I am told that it defaults to the last folder you used.

I am not associated with it.  Maybe there is a market for such an app.